# How to check if a specific value exists in a multidimensional array?

Tags: ruby

I want to check if a specific value exists in a nested array.

I have the following code, which only works with one dimensional arrays:

```
a = [['hello', 'hi', 'hey'], ['bye', 'seeya', 'goodbye']]

def find_a_word(array, word)
  return "Found your word, #{word}" if array.index(word)
end
```

I have also tried using rassoc and assoc, but again it only partially works.

```
def find_word(array, word)
  return "Found your word, #{word}!" if array.rassoc(word) || array.assoc(word)
end
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know you only have an array-of-arrays (i.e. exactly two levels) then you could use [`Array#any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-any-3F) and [`Array#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
array.any? { |a| a.include?(word) }
```

Both `any?` and `include?` short circuit so they'll return `true` as soon as the target is found.

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Is `array.flatten.index(word)` useful?

Comment: You're right, that does work! Thank you. I'm wondering if that's the best way?

Comment: Ralitza, this has the advantage that it works with any level of nesting of arrays. It's fine to use `Array#index` but `Array#include?` arguably reads better and is the more common usage.

Comment: I was initially using Array#include?, but while searching for an answer to this question on SO, I came across several posts that recommended using Array#index instead as it's suppose to be faster?

Comment: @Ralitza If you compare the implementations of [`index`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_5/array.c#L1479) and [`include?`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_5/array.c#L3983) you'll see that `index` does a tiny bit more work (a couple conditionals and some bit twiddling) but they're nearly identical (look at the `for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++)` loops). Any speed difference between the two would be vanishingly small.

Comment: This is an interesting approach +1, but I agree with Cary, `include?` is more semantic plus it returns true/false as required.

Answer (score 2):

can also use **[Array#flatten](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten)** and **[Array#include?](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F)**:

```
> a = [['hello', 'hi', 'hey'], ['bye', 'seeya', 'goodbye']]
> a.flatten.include?("hey")
#=> true
>  a.flatten.include?("Hey")
#=> false
```

for **non case-sensitive**:

```
> word = "hEY"
> a.flatten.map(&:downcase).include?(word.downcase)
#=> true
> word = "HeY"
> a.flatten.map(&:downcase).include?(word.downcase)
#=> true
> word = "HEY"
> a.flatten.map(&:downcase).include?(word.downcase)
#=> true
```

Comment: Be careful with your whitespace, `include? ("hey")` and `include?("hey")` are very different things and the former only works by accident. If you say `m (x)` then the parentheses are grouping-parentheses, if you say `m(x)` then the parentheses are method-calling-parentheses. Doesn't matter with one argument but `m (x, y)` is a syntax error whereas `m(x, y)` is a method call.

Comment: @muistooshort : yes agree, it's typo mistake..thanks for pointing me well detailed

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be,

```
array.flatten.member?('word')
```